# Creating a interactive map on R using plotly

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to create a dynamic map from ggplot2 to plotly.

I tried the following:

```
library(geobr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(ggthemes)


# download sf of Brazilian states
states <- read_state(code_state = 'all')

map <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=states, color="gray90", fill="gray80", size=.4) +
  theme_map() +
  theme( strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"),
         strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8, face ="bold"))
```

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VURKh.jpg)

How can I transform this map into a interactive map ? I am trying to following this example ([Link](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/maps-sf/))

Using plotly, I couldn`t get the that:

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(map)

Error in st_coordinates.sfc(sf::st_geometry(model)) : 
  not implemented for objects of class sfc_GEOMETRY
```

Comment: This appears to be a related issue? https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1659

Comment: HI, Ben. Yes it seems to be related.

Comment: The only solution that I found until now is working with .shp file directly.

Comment: sf::st_read("file.shp")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use the function sf::st_cast('your geobr map dataset', "MULTIPOLYGON").

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(geobr)
library(ggthemes)

states <- read_state(code_state = 'all')
states = sf::st_cast(states, "MULTIPOLYGON")

map <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=states, color="gray90", fill="gray80", size=.4) + 
  theme_map() +
  theme( strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"),
         strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8, face ="bold"))

ggplotly(map)
```

See the discussion here: https://github.com/ipeaGIT/geobr/issues/172